# Create sequence of dates and times in R without time zones

Tags: r, date, datetime, sequence

I need to create a sequence of dates and times in R, increasing in 15 minute periods. 
Currently, I am doing this:

```
datestimes=seq(as.POSIXlt("2011-01-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXlt("2015-09-30 23:45:00"), by="15 min")
```

I should have one reading for each time in the year. The problem is that since it is adjusting for BST, I get two values for certain dates in October.

```
anm=aggregate(datestimes, by=list(datestimes$datestimes), FUN=length)
anm[which(anm$datestimes>1),]

                   Group.1 datestimes X.Date.
28993  2011-10-30 01:00:00          2       2
28994  2011-10-30 01:15:00          2       2
28995  2011-10-30 01:30:00          2       2
28996  2011-10-30 01:45:00          2       2
63933  2012-10-28 01:00:00          2       2
63934  2012-10-28 01:15:00          2       2
63935  2012-10-28 01:30:00          2       2
63936  2012-10-28 01:45:00          2       2
98873  2013-10-27 01:00:00          2       2
98874  2013-10-27 01:15:00          2       2
98875  2013-10-27 01:30:00          2       2
98876  2013-10-27 01:45:00          2       2
133813 2014-10-26 01:00:00          2       2
133814 2014-10-26 01:15:00          2       2
133815 2014-10-26 01:30:00          2       2
133816 2014-10-26 01:45:00          2       2
```

I tried using the as.chron command since this does not use timezones, but it will not allow increments of 15 minutes which is what I need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The problem is that since it is adjusting for BST, I get two values for certain dates in October.

That's because the 'fall back' (mnemonic for daylight savings times adjustment adding an  hour in the fall) happens under *human time* and that is what you get *by default* unless you override it.

```
R> seq(as.POSIXlt("2012-10-28 00:00:00", tz="UTC"), 
+      as.POSIXlt("2012-10-28 03:00:00", tz="UTC"), by="15 min")
 [1] "2012-10-28 00:00:00 UTC" "2012-10-28 00:15:00 UTC"
 [3] "2012-10-28 00:30:00 UTC" "2012-10-28 00:45:00 UTC"
 [5] "2012-10-28 01:00:00 UTC" "2012-10-28 01:15:00 UTC"
 [7] "2012-10-28 01:30:00 UTC" "2012-10-28 01:45:00 UTC"
 [9] "2012-10-28 02:00:00 UTC" "2012-10-28 02:15:00 UTC"
[11] "2012-10-28 02:30:00 UTC" "2012-10-28 02:45:00 UTC"
[13] "2012-10-28 03:00:00 UTC"
R>
```

The example I show here covers the same subset as above *but without the fall back* as we now impose UTC as a time zone.  And UTC has be construction no daylight savings adjustment.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try this (UTC timezone should not allow any duplicate):

```
datestimes=seq(as.POSIXlt("2015-09-01 00:00:00", tz="UTC"), 
               as.POSIXlt("2015-10-30 23:45:00", tz="UTC"), 
               by="15 min")
```